# Javascript plugin for creating select elements from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

Is there any plugin, preferably vanilla but jquery plugins work too, that can turn a JavaScript object into respective select elements.

```
obj = {
    Ford: {
        1: "Focus",
        2: "Fiesta"
    },
    Toyota: {
        1: "Prius",
        2: "Avensis"
    }
}

AwesomePluginMagic(obj);
```

Which should give me

```
<select name="primary">
    <option value="0" selected>Ford</option>
    <option value="1">Toyota</option>

</select>

<select name="secondary">
    <option value="1">Focus</option>
    <option value="2">Fiesta</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="1">Prius</option>
    <option class="hidden" value="2">Avensis</option>
</select>
```

And should  then listen for changes and visualize the appropriate options in the relevant select element.

Disclaimer: I don't want you to write a function for me, I'm asking for a plugin already made, but if you insist I'll use it. Also the input object can be of any format, I just made up one for the example.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, elephant or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. I expected a 4k user to already know that?

Comment: Using Vanilla JS you'd need about 20 lines of code, why to search for a plug-in?

Comment: :Looking at your object model and then at the select that you generated... uhm... is very hard to figure out what exactly you want to generated and plugin that will create exactly that...well, probably as other says will be more complicated than just writing this by hand or with help of some lib like knockout or angular or react that are pretty good at doing this kind of things (binding javascript object to dom element, vice versa).

Comment: @JimmyChandra It's because the proposed output given by OP is wrong... "Toyota" appears nowhere.

Comment: Yeah that code is a bonker... the first list should be Ford / Toyota and when the right option is selected, the second (child) select should change to the appropriate list of the brand and not hide those that are not relevant.  It should just obliterate and recreate that list with new data.  if ford, then it will be focus / fiesta, and if toyota, then it will only have prius and avensis.

Comment: Here is similar master detail select list fiddle that I created a while back, perhaps you can figure out something from it.  I was using Knockout to do the binding: http://jsfiddle.net/jchandra/99h0zwjg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example on how to implement this without any library.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    
    var obj = {
        Ford: {            
            1: "Focus",
            2: "Fiesta"            
        },
        Toyota: {            
            1: "Prius",
            2: "Avensis"            
        }
    };
    
    var manufacturers = Object.keys(obj);
    var selectedManufacturer = manufacturers[0];
    var models = hashTokeyValuePairArray(obj[selectedManufacturer]);
    var selectedModel = models[0];
    var selectedCar = { make: selectedManufacturer, model: selectedModel.value };

    bindManufacturer();
    bindModel();    
    bindSelectedCar();
    
    function hashTokeyValuePairArray(o) {
        var k = Object.keys(o);        
        return k.map(function(k) { return { key: k, value: o[k] }; });
    }
    
    function bindSelectedMake() {
        var el = document.getElementById("selectedMake");
        el.innerText = selectedManufacturer;
    }
    
    function bindSelectedModel() {
        var el = document.getElementById("selectedModel");
        el.innerText = selectedModel.value;
    }

    function bindSelectedCar() {
        bindSelectedMake();
        bindSelectedModel();
        
        selectedCar = { make: selectedManufacturer, model: selectedModel.value };
        console.log(selectedCar);
    }
    
    function bindManufacturer() {
        var el = document.getElementById("make");    
        var opts = manufacturers.map(function(m) { return "<option>" + m + "</option>"; });     
        el.innerHTML = opts.join('');        
        el.options.selectedIndex = 0;
        el.addEventListener('change', function() {
            selectedManufacturer = manufacturers[this.options.selectedIndex];
            models = hashTokeyValuePairArray(obj[selectedManufacturer]);
            selectedModel = models[0];
            bindModel(true);
            bindSelectedCar();
        });
    }
    
    function bindModel(skipEventBinding) {
        var el = document.getElementById("model");
        var opts = models.map(function(m) { return "<option value=\"" + m.key + "\">" + m.value + "</option>"; });
        el.innerHTML = opts.join('');
        el.options.selectedIndex = 0;
        
        if (!skipEventBinding) {
            el.addEventListener('change', function() {
                selectedModel = models[this.options.selectedIndex];
                bindSelectedCar();
            });
        }
    }
}());
```

```css
#make, #model { width: 100px; margin-bottom:5px }
```

```html
<label for="make">Make:</label> <select id="make"></select>
<label for="model">Model:</label> <select id="model">
</select>

<div>
    Selected Car: <span id="selectedMake"></span> <span id="selectedModel"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added a `data-car` value to the secondary options so they have a reference to the primary `select`. Also added a `change` listener for the primary which changes the `.hidden` for the secondary options based on the selected item.

Disclaimer: It will work with the current format, if obj has a different format it needs to be modified. I don't think it's possible though, unless some restrictions are set for the format of the given object.

```
function AwesomePluginMagic(obj) {

    var prm = document.createElement('select');
    var scnd = document.createElement('select');
    prm.name = "primary";
    scnd.name = "secondary";

    var i = 1;
    for(var itm in obj) {
        var popt = document.createElement('option');
        popt.value = i;
        popt.innerHTML = itm;
        prm.appendChild(popt);
        var j = 1;
        for(var sub in obj[itm]) {
            var sopt = document.createElement('option');
            sopt.setAttribute('data-car', i);
            sopt.value = j;
            sopt.innerHTML = obj[itm][sub];
            if(i > 1)
                sopt.className = "hidden";
            scnd.appendChild(sopt);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    var dv = document.getElementById('dv');
    dv.appendChild(prm);
    dv.appendChild(scnd);
    prm.addEventListener('change', function() {
        var selected = false;
        var o = scnd.options;
        for(var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
            if(o[i].getAttribute('data-car') == this.value) {
                o[i].className =  "";
                if(!selected) {
                    o[i].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
                    selected = true;
                }
            }
            else
                o[i].className = "hidden";
        }
    });
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/3px64p2b/1/)

Answer (score 1):

JS is object oriented, why not use objects, something like this:

```js
var // Data
    cars = {
        Ford: {
            1: "Focus",
            2: "Fiesta",
        },
        Toyota: {
            1: "Prius",
            2: "Avensis"
        }
    },
    // The AwesomePlugin
    selectPair = Object.create({}, {
        update: {value: function (select, obj) {
            var keys = Object.keys(obj).sort(function (a, b) {return a.localeCompare(b);}),
                n, eN, option, element = this[select] || document.createElement('select');
            element.length = 0;
            for (n = 0, eN = keys.length; n < eN; n ++) {
                option = document.createElement('option');
                option.text = (typeof obj[keys[n]] === 'object') ? keys[n] : obj[keys[n]];
                option.value = (typeof obj[keys[n]] === 'object') ? keys[n] : obj[keys[n]];
                element.appendChild(option);
            }
            return element;
        }},
        init: {value: function (obj, target) {
            var that = this, keys = Object.keys(obj).sort(function (a, b) {return a.localeCompare(b);});
            this.host = target.appendChild(this.update('host', obj));
            this.child = target.appendChild(this.update('child', obj[keys[0]]));
            this.host.addEventListener('change', function () {
                that.update('child', obj[that.host.value]);
            });
            return this;
        }}
     });
// Usage
Object.create(selectPair).init(cars, document.body);
```

The prototype is reusable, you can create multiple "select pairs" just by creating a new object using `selectPair` prototype and passing the needed data object and the element to append the `select` elements.